# How to convert XSD to oracle database schema

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Please tell me how can I get oracle database schema out of XSD provided. Here is the code, I'm passing

**Step 1 :**

```
begin dbms_xmlschema.registerSchema('xdb_usr.xsd',
'<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:per="xdb_usr.xsd"
            xmlns:xdb="http://xmlns.oracle.com/xdb">
 <xs:element name = "Employee1"
        xdb:defaultTable="EMP31B_TAB">
   <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name = "EmployeeId" type = "xs:positiveInteger"/>
      <xs:element name = "Name" type = "xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name = "Salary" type = "xs:positiveInteger"/>
      <xs:element name = "DeptId" type = "xs:positiveInteger"
             xdb:SQLName="DEPTID"/>
    </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
</xs:schema>',
TRUE, TRUE, FALSE); end;
```

**Step2:** `CREATE TABLE foo OF XMLType XMLSCHEMA "xdb_usr.xsd" ELEMENT "Employee1";`

**Step3:**

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE ''
INTO TABLE foo TRUNCATE
xmltype(xmldata)
(
  xmldata   char(4000)
)
BEGINDATA
<Employee1>  <EmployeeId>111</EmployeeId>  <Name>Ravi</Name>  <Salary>100000</Sal
ary>  <DeptId>12</DeptId></Employee1>
<Employee1>  <EmployeeId>112</EmployeeId>  <Name>John</Name>  <Salary>150000</Sal
ary>  <DeptId>12</DeptId></Employee1>
<Employee1>  <EmployeeId>113</EmployeeId>  <Name>Michael</Name>  <Salary>75000</S
alary>  <DeptId>12</DeptId></Employee1>
<Employee1>  <EmployeeId>114</EmployeeId>  <Name>Mark</Name>  <Salary>125000</Sal
ary>  <DeptId>16</DeptId></Employee1>
<Employee1>  <EmployeeId>115</EmployeeId>  <Name>Aaron</Name>  <Salary>600000</Sa
lary>  <DeptId>16</DeptId></Employee1>
```

Whenever I run Step1, it register Schema and when I run Step 2 it creates table. And When I run Step 3: its says loaded data. however, I can see table created but couldn't find table with schema defined and with any data. Your help is much appreciated. Below is the snapshot showing my table with null schema..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a keyword (COLUMN) :

```
CREATE TABLE foo (EMP XMLType) XMLType COLUMN EMP XMLSCHEMA "xdb_usr.xsd" ELEMENT "Employee1";

select *  from FOO ;
```